# How to handle NoSuchElementException() globally in selenium C# project

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, nunit

I'm working on selenium with `C#` and using `NUNIT 3.0` framework. I have approx 200 test cases and i do not want to put try catch for all 300 test cases as there are always a possibility that this exception may occur in any test case. What i need is to handle it globally in my project.

It will really be appreciated if any one provides any input. plz ask if anything else is needed.

My Setup class code format is :

```
namespace HUB_REGRESSION
{
    [SetUpFixture]
    public class BaseSetup
    {
        public static IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            /* Code to visit site URL and Login */

            //- I assume Global Exception handling code will go here as i have globally defined the implicit wait time-//
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always add extensions for both IWebDriver and IWebElement. See 2 example extension methods below:

```
public static class WebDriverExtension
{
    public static ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElementsBy(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutSecond = 0)
    {
        IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new DefaultWait<IWebDriver>(driver);
        wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout);
        wait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);
        try
        {
            wait.Until(d => d.FindElements(by).Count > 0);
            return driver.FindElements(by);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Unable to find element, locator: \"" + by.ToString() + "\".");
        }
    }

    public static ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FindElementsBy(this IWebElement element, By by, int timeout = 0)
    {
        IWait<IWebElement> wait = new DefaultWait<IWebElement>(element);
        wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout);
        wait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);
        try
        {
            wait.Until(e => e.FindElements(by).Count > 0);
            return element.FindElements(by);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Unable to find element, locator: \"" + by.ToString() + "\".");
        }
    }
}
```

In your test, you can all the extension method:

```
public void ATestMethod()
{
    IWebElement element = driver.FindElementsBy(By.Id("anID"), 5).First();
    element.FindElementsBy(By.Id("ID2"), 3)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Buaban but I could not figure how to use it and how its going to benefit in this scenario.

Comment: You have to create a file name 'WebDriverExtension.cs'. In this new file, add a static class 'WebDriverExtension' and add the 2 methods in my answer. Then in your test case, using the namespace of the class 'WebDriverExtension'. Now you can use the extension methods directly from your webdriver object such as `driver.FindElementsBy` or `element.FindElementsBy`.